# Parameter in class that has this class type

Tags: c++

```
    class Vertex {

    public:
        Vertex* previous_vertex_id;

        Vertex::Vertex() {}
        Vertex::~Vertex() {}
}
```

Now it compiles, but I need strictly **previous_vertex_id** *without pointer*, it's for further code, that uses this property. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You want on object that contains an instance of itself? Impossible. Consider the size of this object for a proof.

Comment: _"but I need strictly previous_vertex_id without pointer"_ You mean you need a reference? That's hardly going to work at all.

Comment: Obviously you never implement it! because there is a loop including, although you use reference, the reference must be initialized in the constructor.

Comment: Could you elaborate why it cannot be a pointer? Being a pointer doesn't affect other codes' ability to use it. (Unless you're saying there's a lot of code with `previous_vertex_id.x` already which would need to be changed to `previous_vertex_id->x`)

Comment: I'm guessing you want to pass it to a function that receives an object not a pointer, and that's why you'd like its type to be non-pointer. Pass it as so: *previous_vertex_id, and you got the object. (Make sure to check for nullptr first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a class with itself as a member, the size of such an object would be infinite. A `Vertex` which contains a `Vertex` which contains a `Vertex` etc.

It seems, from this question, and [one you posted earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36385061/cycle-that-uses-pointer-it-is-endless), that you want something java-like, but in C++. You want something like this:

```
class Vertex {

public:
    Vertex* previous_vertex_id;
    ...
    void setPrevious(Vertex &v) {
        previous_vertex_id = &v;
    }

    Vertex &getPrevious() {
        return (*previous_vertex_id); // trusting that the pointer will still be valid.
    }
}
```

Now, it is important to know when in C++, an object is copied and when an object is referenced. With the `Vertex` class I just described:

```
Vertex v1{}; // construct a new vertex
Vertex v2{}; // construct a new vertex

// v3 is a copy of v1, they are separate objects at different memory locations.
Vertex v3 = v1;

// v4 is a reference to v1, they are the same object under a different name.
Vertex &v4 = v1;

// v1.previous_vertex_id is a pointer to v2.
v1.setPrevious(v2);

// v5 is a copy of v2. A different object at a different memory location.
Vertex v5 = v1.getPrevious();

// v6 is a reference to v2, they are the same object under a different name.
Vertex &v6 = v1.getPrevious();
```

Now you can use `getPrevious` to access the previous vertex as a non-pointer. Just be careful in which way you assign it, so you only copy it when intended (`v5`/`v6` example).

Answer (score -3):

just write

```
Vertex previous_vertex_id;
```

in the private section. don't use `*`

Comment: This will have a copy of whatever `Vertex` in that instance. That's not useful.

Comment: store the value by reference then

Comment: As mentioned storing a reference won't work well, there's need for `nullptr` to indicate there's no `previous_vertex_id`.

Comment: you're right. it will not work like this and it's seems impossible to add class's own reference into it's own private data member.